# Reading Header from another file? Word Javascript API Add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I need to convert this old vba code into the new Office/Word Javascript API Add-in version.

I just can't seem to find any online documentation where Word Add-in Javascript API can access data from another document file. Is it even possible?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  Dim docTemplate As Document
  Dim strTemplate As String
  Dim hdr1 As HeaderFooter
  Dim hdr2 As HeaderFooter
  Dim doc As Document

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  strTemplate = "C:\wizards\LondonLetterHead.dot"
  Set docTemplate = GetObject(strTemplate)
  Set hdr1 = docTemplate.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
  Set hdr2 = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
  hdr2.Range.FormattedText = hdr1.Range
  docTemplate.Close False
End Sub
```

Can the Javascript API do something like the VBA code I provided?

Comment: That depends on where this file needs to reside and the what/why of changing it. The JS APIs are "sand-boxed" - they can't open files from the user's drive, so a literal conversion of the example in the question is not possible. OTOH, it's possible to work with closed files via the Office Open XML file format that are in an on-line location and that Open XML can be written to the document.

Comment: Thanks Cindy. I think in that case, the latter one (Office Open XML format) works for me. I can definitely upload dotx files somewhere. I suppose onedrive/sharepoint is considered as "on-line location"? I just need to end up with an add-in that is easy to deploy (via centralized deployment).

Comment: Can someone show a sample JS API that access headers from OOXML file that is located on-line location? No need to be too specific, just need to know some key commands to use. Thanks!!!